# TOTP tokens do not match

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to implement TOTP, but I'm having a problem because the Token output by Google Authenticator and the result calculated here do not match.

Development environment：Java（Servlet） Eclipse

1. Generate Key

   I use Google Authentication to generate a Key from my username with key.getKey () and use Base32 () to encode it.

   ```
   final GoogleAuthenticatorKey key = gAuth.createCredentials( userName );

   key.getKey()
   Use Apache Base32()
   ```
2. Generate QR Code

   Generate a QR code. See also the image.

   [image: Display QR Code]

   ```
   <script src="/js/qrcode.min.js"></script>


   otpauth://totp/takao.ehara?
   secret=IU3U2U2SINBEQWSWJNCUINC2KVLEMSKYLFLFCNRUJ5JTMS2RLBKQ&
   issuer=Takao Ehara Corporation&digits=6&period=30
   ```
3. Use iPhone's google authenticator to get a token.

   ```
   log : Token     = 723025
   ```
4. HMAC_SHA256

   Generate Hash with SHA256 algorithm based on key.

   ```
    log : HS = HMAC-SHA-1( K, C ) :
       K = IU3U2U2SINBEQWSWJNCUINC2KVLEMSKYLFLFCNRUJ5JTMS2RLBKQ

       Variables : K = secretKey


       SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, HMAC_SHA256 );
       Mac mac = Mac.getInstance( HMAC_SHA256 );
       mac.init(sks);
       byte[] hmacBytes = mac.doFinal();

       return hmacBytes;
   ```
5. resultStr

   The generated HASH is as follows.

   ```
   Variables : HS = hmacBytes

   HS = 3c72f2b3802ab9b8a210ea992c436683ddd73c6a9cf55bfcb30921e7b359e1e4
   ```
6. result = 514302

   See Also: RFC 4226 - HOTP

   ```
   The hash length is 32. 
   log : hash.length = 32

   Hash, get the lower 4 bits of the 32nd byte. 
   HS = 3c72f2b3802ab9b8a210ea992c436683ddd73c6a9cf55bfcb30921e7b359e1e [4]
   ```

   In this case, offset is 4.

   ```
   log : offset = 4
   ```

   Get 4 bytes from the 4th byte of hash.

   ```
   HS = 3c72f2b3 [802ab9b8] a210ea992c436683ddd73c6a9cf55bfcb30921e7b359e1e4

   log : e = 8 0 2 a b 9 b 8
   ```

   OR each byte.

   ```
   long e0 = numeric[0] << 28;
   long e1 = numeric[1] << 24;
   long e2 = numeric[2] << 20;
   long e3 = numeric[3] << 16;
   long e4 = numeric[4] << 12;
   long e5 = numeric[5] << 8;
   long e6 = numeric[6] << 4;
   long e7 = numeric[7] << 0;

   // e0 = 8, e1 = 0, e2 = 2, e3 = a, e4 = b, e5 = 9, e6 = b, e7 = 8

    long truncate = (long)( e0 | e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 | e5 | e6 | e7 );

    log : truncate = 2150283704
   ```

   I'll put the source code on the fllowing line.

   ```
   ***********************

   // HOTP computation for Digit = 6
   // D = Snum modulo 10 ^ 6
   long pow = (long)Math.pow( 10, 6 );
   long hotp = (long)( truncate % pow );


   // zero press
   String totp = String.format( "%06d", (int)hotp );

   ***********************
   ```
7. It does not match.

   ```
   Token  = 723025(from Google Authenticator)
   result = 514302(this)
   ```

[image: running on eclipse Show log]

Comment: I don't know why you're getting downvotes and close votes, this is a fine question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you generating a new hash? You should just use IU3U2U2SINBEQWSWJNCUINC2KVLEMSKYLFLFCNRUJ5JTMS2RLBKQ (probably need to convert to hex)

Comment: Thank you. It went well.　https://twitter.com/TakaoEhara_jp/status/1416670771850616835